# php preg_replace how to exclude case

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following `preg_replace`

```
foreach ($financeTermsArray as $term => $info) {

   $content = preg_replace($term, $info, $content, 1);
}
```

where the $info variable looks like

`'<a class="glossar-word" href="' . get_permalink() . '"  data-glossar="' . $excerpt . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';`

and `$term` variable like `"/\b" . get_the_title() . "\b/"`

I want to exclude from `preg_replace` if matched word is inside `data-glossar` html attribute.

How would I do this?

**I got it working with the following pattern:**

`"/data-glossar=\"([^\"]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|\b" . get_the_title() . "\b/"`

Comment: where is the regex?

Comment: `matched word` is equal to what's returned from `get_the_title()` So, you'd have to incorporate what `get_the_title()` returns into a regex that skips the tag that contains that value within the `data-glossar` attribute. Is that what you want ? Or do you need to exclude ALL tags in general first ?

Comment: yes that would be the idea because `$content` is getting updated on loop matches and data attribute value may contain the keyword and on that case should be skipped.

Comment: `I want to exclude from preg_replace if matched word is inside data-glossar html attribute.` and `I got it working with the following pattern:` actually the pattern doesn't technically match that attribute, since its not a tag/attribute regex. My regex excludes all html so it will never fail and will never have ambiguity. If I gave you the idea of _SKIP/FAIL_ can you kindly accept and upvote my answer ?

Comment: Btw, `"\b/"` should be `"\\b/"` for safety.

Comment: should not exclude all html tags, should exclude matched case inside data attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that is constructed with the `get_the_title()` at runtime.
When the  regex is constructed, it will *SKIP ALL TAGS* in html, including
invisible content, and will only match the `'\b' . get_the_title() . '\b'`
as found *OUTSIDE* tags.

I don't have anyway to test out the resulting regex string, so you should do that
first and see if it looks ok.

Use this on a preg_replace as originally intended.

```
$term = '~<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'
        . '\b' . get_the_title() . '\b~';
```